# Is there guided recording of classical music?

Tags: classical-music

I had the good fortune of taking an Intro to Harmony and some piano lessons in college, which opened my eyes to the fact that music has structure and meaning. "Getting" a piece this way instead of just listening to it is much more satisfying I found.

However, even though I know that a piece has a structure, I'm not skilled enough to recognize it myself. It's as if I knew there's a treasure buried somewhere around here but had no way to discover it.

Is there such a thing as a guided recording of classical music, where the structure of the music is explained, what possibly is the composer's intent, and even how this piece fits into its historical context? Similar to a tour guide in a museum, this would brings so much more meaning to the art.

Comment: "Young People's Guide to the Orchestra."  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vbvhU22uAM

Comment: The conductor Joshua Weilerstein has an excellent podcast, Sticky Notes, that might fit the bill and which I don't think existed in 2015 when this question was originally asked: https://joshuaweilerstein.com/stickynotes

Answer (score 3):

Search YouTube for Bernstein's Young Peoples' Concerts. Too numerous to link to one here.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for Andras Schiff's lectures on the Beethoven piano sonatas.  (Note some people have debated the accuracy of his historical information about the dates and influences, but his basic interpretations are interesting.)